Incorrect redirection to login page from profile and logout links after user login
Context
I'm working on a Django project where I have implemented user authentication with profile and logout functionality. The issue I'm encountering is that when I try to access the profile or logout links from the navbar, it redirects me to the login page instead of navigating to the user's profile or performing logout.
Profile Link
Should navigate to the user's profile page if the user is logged in.
Logout Link
Should log out the user and redirect to the homepage.
Current Setup - templates (base.html):
{% if logged_in %}
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        {{ customer_name }}
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="userDropdown">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'profile' %}?email={{ customer_email }}">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
{% endif %}

Views:
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login as auth_login, logout as auth_logout
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import customer

@login_required
def profile_view(request):
    email = request.GET.get('email')
    if email:
        try:
            user = customer.objects.get(email=email)
            if user.id == request.session.get('customer_id'):
                return render(request, 'profile.html', {'user': user})
            else:
                return redirect('index')
        except customer.DoesNotExist:
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        return redirect('index')

def logout_view(request):
    request.session.flush()
    auth_logout(request)
    return redirect('index')

def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        try:
            customer = customer.objects.get(email=email)
            if customer.check_password(password):
                request.session['customer_id'] = customer.id
                request.session['logged_in'] = True
                request.session['customer_name'] = f"{customer.first_name} {customer.last_name}"
                request.session['customer_email'] = customer.email
                messages.success(request, "Logged in!!")
                return redirect('index')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Incorrect password')
        except customer.DoesNotExist:
            messages.error(request, 'Email not found')

    return render(request, 'login.html')

URLs:
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('login/', views.login_view, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
    path('profile/', views.profile_view, name='profile'),
]

Session management:

Session variables are set in login_view and cleared in logout_view.

Debugging steps taken

Printed session data in different views to confirm if customer_id and customer_name are correctly set.
Observed that clicking on the profile or logout links always redirects to the login page.

Issue
Could you help me figure out why these links are redirecting to the login page instead of showing the profile or logging out properly? Specifically, I need assistance verifying session handling and ensuring correct redirection.

Does the base.html correctly detect if you're logged in; ie.: does it show the profile & logout links once you've logged in?

Well. Your logout view redirects to the index explicitly, so that behavior seems expected. Your profile view is decorated with @login_required and your login view does set some session parameters, but it's not clear to me that the login view actually logs in the user as the views decorated with @login_required would expect -- that is to say, you're not calling login()

You'r login view is not properly logging in the user. The login view is expected to call the login() function, but your view does not call this function. Because your profile view is decorated with @login_required you will not be able to access the view unless you are logged in.
It looks like you have implemented custom logic for logging in the user, but this will not inherently work with Django's builtin auth system, such as the @login_required decorator.
You must modify your login_view to correctly call the login function, as demonstrated in the example docs:
def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST["username"]
    password = request.POST["password"]
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user) # <--- You are missing this call!
        # Redirect to a success page.
        ...
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
        ...

